# Why does pandas sometimes seems to change the string encoding when selecting a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a dataset that has latin accents on some column names. When working with a subset of the data on the Ipython console of spyder3 no errors occur, but when passing this into a script and running it on the complete dataset suddenly a "Keyerror" pops up.

For example:

```
df = df.read_excel("Data.xlsx")

total = df['Denominación']['Value'].sum()
```

works fine on the console but gives "KeyError: 'DenominaciÃ³n'" when run as a script.

I just changed my column names to fix the 'problem' but I am curious as to why this happens.

Answer (score 2):

Did you put on your file these initial lines? Seems like a missing utf-8 declaration problem, even though it should be automatic in python3

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, those lines are at the start.

Comment: And it still doesn't work? If so copy paste your file here, I crated a dataframe with same columns and I can print it from shell without any issue.